# Creating tree from given path of string list in f#

Tags: f#, tree, filesystems

I have a type defination:

```
type FsTree = Node of (string * FsTree) list
```

I create an empty node:

```
let createEmptyFsTree () : FsTree = Node[]
```

I would love to build a tree from a path of string list, for example:

```
let fs1 = create ["MainNode";"nodeA";"nodeB"] (createEmptyFsTree())
let fs2 = create ["MainNode";"nodeC";"nodeD"] fs1
let fs3 = create ["MainNode";"nodeC";"nodeE"] fs2
```

The result will be:

```
Node [("MainNode", Node [

                             ("nodeA", Node [("nodeB", Node [])]);
                             ("nodeC", Node [
                                         ("nodeD", Node[]);
                                         ("nodeE", Node[])])])]
```

This is my code so far. I have been stuck for 2 days. Please help.

```
let create (p : string list) (fs : FsTree) =
        let rec create (p : string list) (fs : FsTree) =
            match fs with 
            | Node n -> match p, n with
                        | h :: t, (name, rsNode) :: rsTree when name = h -> Node([(h, (create t rsNode))] @ rsTree)
                        | _, lNode :: rsTree -> Node([lNode]@rsTree)
                        | h :: t, [] -> Node ([h, (create t (createEmptyFsTree()))])
                        | [],[] -> Node[]
        create p fs
```

I am only able to create the tree from the first path passed:

```
Node [("MainNode", Node [("nodeA", Node [("nodeB", Node [])])])]
```

Comment: Notice that you have a `create` inside another. The outside `create` only calls the one inside so it does not do anything you could eliminate that one and the result would be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty of this problem is that there are several structures (the path is a `list`, each node is a `list` and a subtree) that need to be traversed recursively at the same time in order for it to work. Doing so in just one function becomes very hard to figure out.

That is why I like to simplify the problem by breaking it down into smaller parts. Here we are going to use 2 mutually recursive functions (notice the syntax). First I am going to rename the functions so that I understand better what they do. I also avoid repeating the same name for functions and variables as it is confusing. My first function will only deal with traversing the path `p`:

```
let rec addPath (p : string list)   (Node ns) =
    match p with
    | []       -> Node                    ns
    | hp :: tp -> Node (addHeadPath hp tp ns)
```

I use pattern matching on the second parameter `(Node ns)` to get the list of subnodes, that is because the next function will traverse that list.

In my `match` expression I like to take care first of the empty list case which is the end of the recursion. The second case separates the head and tail and sends them to another function to deal with it:

```
and addHeadPath hp tp ns =
    match ns with
    | []                          -> [hp, addPath tp (Node[]) ]
    | (nn, st) :: tn when nn = hp -> (nn, addPath tp st       ) ::                   tn
    | hn       :: tn              -> hn                         :: addHeadPath hp tp tn
```

`addHeadPathTo` is mutually recursive with `addPathTo` so I tie them together with `and` instead of another `let rec`.

Again the empty case is dealt with first which returns a list with one node and calls `addPathTo` to add the rest of the path. The second case is when the node already exists in which case we add the rest of the path to the subtree `st`. The third case keeps looking into the list of nodes by calling itself recursively.

You invoke it this way:

```
createEmptyFsTree()
|> addPath ["MainNode";"nodeA";"nodeB"] 
|> addPath ["MainNode";"nodeC";"nodeD"]
|> addPath ["MainNode";"nodeC";"nodeE"]    
|> printfn "%A"
```